# How to access array elements inside json?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have the following array as part of a json schema.

```
"CurrentAgentSnapshot": {
    "Configuration": {
        "Contacts": []
     }
}
```

How can i access the contacts element using oracle sql developer?
Below is a snippet of my code that has syntax error at the square bracket position. Do i need a temporary variable to hold the contacts variable

```
DECLARE 
        callDuration VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            tbl.event_data.currentagentsnapshot.contacts
        FROM
            tbl_agent_event_json tbl;
    BEGIN
       callDuration := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - tbl.event_data.currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0].StateStartTimestamp;
    END;
```

Comment: SQL developer is a tool used to access database and not the type of database. Which version of Oracle are you using ? Where have you saved the json string?  Why are you using two BEGIN..END in your code? and why is there no into clause in your select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_array or json_arrayagg

Example:
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db122/ADJSN/generation.htm#ADJSN-GUID-B0FA4582-762D-4C32-8A0C-265142BD347B

```
SELECT json_object('id'         VALUE mgr.employee_id, 
                   'manager'    VALUE (mgr.first_name || ' '|| mgr.last_name),
                   'numReports' VALUE count(rpt.employee_id),
                   'reports'    VALUE json_arrayagg(rpt.employee_id
                                                    ORDER BY rpt.employee_id))
  FROM  employees mgr, employees rpt
  WHERE mgr.employee_id = rpt.manager_id
  GROUP BY mgr.employee_id, mgr.last_name, mgr.first_name
  HAVING count(rpt.employee_id) > 6;
```